# Simaltaneous trignometric equation in python

Tags: python-3.x

My task is to simulate a 3 DOF robotic arm system in python. The aim is to trace out a 3D Gaussian surface. Input data is coordinates of the end effector gained using 3D Gaussian equation. The code is supposed to solve a system of the trigonometric equation to find out angles theta1, theta2 & theta3. I used "solve([eqn1,eqn2,eqn3],theta1,theta2,theta3)" to solve for the system of equation. Python is taking a too long time to respond.

I tried solving using fsolve, but the results were incomparable to the solution from MATLAB. Btw, I got a very good simulation in MATLAB using "solve".

I am using Python 3.7.3 through spyder under Anaconda 2019.03 environment in Windows 10.

Generating data set (Gaussian surface) : P matrix

```
a = 8
x0 = 0
y0 = 0

sigmax = 3
sigmay = 3

P_x = np.arange(7,-8,-1)
P_y = np.arange(7,-8,-1)

xx , yy = np.meshgrid(P_x,P_y)

s_x,s_y = np.subtract(xx,x0),np.subtract(yy,y0)

sq_x,sq_y = np.square(s_x),np.square(s_y)

X,Y = np.divide(sq_x,2*(sigmax**2)),np.divide(sq_y,2*(sigmay**2))

E = np.exp(-X-Y)

zz = np.multiply(E,a)

xx,yy,zz = xx.flatten(),yy.flatten(),zz.flatten()
P = np.vstack([yy,xx,zz]).T
```

```
import numpy as np
from sympy import *
from sympy import Symbol, solve, Eq

for j in range(len(P)):

    theta1 = Symbol('theta1',real = True)
    theta2 = Symbol('theta2',real = True)
    theta3 = Symbol('theta3',real = True)

    x,y,z = P[j,0],P[j,1],P[j,2]

    eq1 = Eq(R1*cos(theta1) + R2*cos(theta1)*cos(theta2) + 
    R3*cos(theta1)*cos(theta3) - x)

    eq2 = Eq(R1*sin(theta1) + R2*cos(theta2)*sin(theta1) + 
    R3*cos(theta3)*sin(theta1) - y)

    eq3 = Eq(R2*sin(theta2) + R3*sin(theta3) -z )

    solve([eq1,eq2,eq3],theta1,theta2,theta3)

    solution[j,0] = degrees(theta1)

    solution[j,1] = degrees(theta3)

    solution[j,2] = degrees(theta2)
```

Expected result: Solution matrix with values of theta1, theta2 & theta3.

Python takes too much time to respond.

Comment: A couple of questions for clarification: what does P look like? (size, shape, content) What exactly do you mean with "Python takes too much time to respond"? Are we talking about 100ms, 1sec, 10seconds? What performance goal are you aiming for?

Comment: It's an inverse kinematics problem. P matrix stores 225 different coordinates of the end effector. P is a 225 x 3 matrix. The columns represent x,y,z coordinates for 225 different locations. For this particular data set of 225 points, I waited for about 45 minutes....but nothing happened. I even tried with 1 data point but Python only went into solving mode & didn't respond. I am not concerned about speed. But as I wrote, Python wasn't solving even for a single data point. Thank you.

Comment: I added the code for generation of the P matrix. It basically stores 225 different points from a Gaussian surface.